# Email Function does not work in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, titanium

I have two pages with email function when move to second page and return back to first page email does not work. But if we are first time on first page and click email button email works fine. Any idea how to solve this issue.

Page One

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <button onclick="sendMailOne()" >Press to send mail</button>
   <a href="secondPage.html"><h1>Go to second Page</h1></a>


   <script type="text/javascript">


       function sendMailOne(){
          alert("Sending mail . . . . .");
          Titanium.App.fireEvent("sendEmail",{
             "toEmail": "",
             "toName": "",
             "subject": "Test Subject",
             'isHTML':true,
             "body": "Send tdhe mail . . .. . . ",
          });
       }
   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the second page when we move to this from page and come back to first page email does not work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>In second Page</h1>
      <a href="index.html"><h1>Go Back</h1></a>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please submit the email, go to page 2 then go back (when you go back refresh the page then try to submit- if it works then you maybe have to add)

```
$().ready(function() {
```